# How to get recent data and previous data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

If we have the following data, I want to get the data using the "SomeID" column or The "ApplicationID". So the data returned is basically the Amount in separate columns based on the "SomeID"

```
  ID    SomeID ApplicationID    Amount
    19  8      19               45.18
    20  8      20               45.18
    21  8      21               225.91
    22  8      22               203.32
    72  10     19               45.18
    73  10     20               45.18
    74  10     21               225.91
    75  10     22               203.32
```

I want to return

```
Last Month repayment    This Month repaymnrt    Variance
45.18                   45.18                    0
45.18                   45.18                    0
225.91                  225.91                   0
203.32                  203.32                   0
```

Comment: Look for pivot sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using `pivot` or conditional aggregatoin:

```
select applicationId,
       sum(case when someId = 8 then Amount else 0 end) as LastMonth,
       sum(case when someId = 10 then Amount else 0 end) as ThisMonth,
       sum(case when someId = 8 then -Amount 
                when someId = 10 then Amount
                else 0
           end) as Diff
from t
group by applicationId;
```

Comment: Thank you very very much